# Is there any general solution exist for $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{B(x+i, i)}$ function?

Tags: distributions

$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{B(x+i, i)} = \frac{1}{B(x+1, 1)} + \frac{1}{B(x+2, 2)} + \ldots + \frac{1}{B(x+N, N)}$

where ${N}$ is fixed value. is there any simple expression exist for x in the above expression?

or x converges to somewhere if ${N}$ is enoughly large?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. As written, this question can be more suitably answered at the [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site. If this is a Mathematica related question, then please include code that you have tried so far and include a definition for `B`. Also note that `N` is a reserved symbol in Mathematica. Thanks.

Comment: Define $B$.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Assuming that `B` represents the Euler [`beta`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Beta.html) function

```
(sum[n_, x_] = Inactive[Sum][1/Beta[x + i, i], {i, 1, n}]) // 
  TraditionalForm
```

[image]

This sum is

```
(sum[n_, x_] = sum[n, x] // Activate // FullSimplify) // 
  TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The infinite sum diverges; however, it can be Borel [`regularized`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Regularization.html)

```
(sumReg[x_] = Sum[1/Beta[x + i, i], {i, 1, ∞},
    Regularization -> "Borel"]) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

**EDIT:** As noted by Roman, `sumReg[x]` can be simplified

```
(sumReg[x_] = sumReg[x] // FullSimplify) // 
  TraditionalForm
```

[image]

This function has odd symmetry

```
sumReg[-x] == -sumReg[x] // FullSimplify

(* True *)

Plot[sumReg[x], {x, 0, 10 π},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, sumReg})]
```

[image]

Comment: Using `FullSimplify` on the Borel-regularized result gives a much simpler $\frac{1}{9} \left(\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{3}\right)-3 x \cos \left(\frac{\pi 
   x}{3}\right)\right)$.

Comment: @Roman - thanks, I added that.

Comment: Instead of bitmap images of `TraditionalForm` expressions, you can use `TeXForm` and paste the result here for automatic rendering.